# Caching Maven dependencies in Gitlab-CI correctly

Tags: maven, caching, continuous-integration, gitlab

I have configured and working following setup

- gitlab-ci, which uses docker-machine runner and uploads cache to S3
- maven build with configured caching
- caching correctly loads and uploads on each job

But the problem is, that every time I run `mvn install`, something in the local maven repository changes (I assume it updates pom metadata) and gitlab runner keeps uploading new versions of the cache, on every single build.

[image]

It is still faster and more reliable to use this "busted" cache, than to download the deps from internet every time, but the upload can take a long time and I would like to shave off this extra time.

How can I modify my build to force maven, to generate **cacheable** local repository?

Simplified version of my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
variables:
  # we have a custom java+maven image, that uses this ENV variable,
  # to auto-configure path where to put the local maven repository
  MAVEN_LOCAL_REPOSITORY: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cache/maven

job-build:
  stage: build
  image: internal-gitlab/java/maven:3.6-jdk8-alpine
  script:
    - mvn -B clean package
  cache:
    key: backend-dependencies
    paths:
      - .cache/
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a constant as a cache key. Maybe a more fine grained cache would help.
[See the  link here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/merge_requests/2436)

Comment: Actually, this is a maven-specific problem and there is not much I can do about it by configuring Gitlab differently.

Answer (score -2):

In short - prepare your own maven image with required dependencies and use it instead of internal-gitlab/java/maven:3.6-jdk8-alpine.

Some details:

First of all, you need to create a maven docker image where all (or most of) required for your project dependencies are presented. Publish it to your registry (gitlab has one) and use it instead of internal-gitlab/java/maven:3.6-jdk8-alpine.

To create such an image I usually create an additional job in CI triggered manually. You need to trigger it at initial stage and when project dependencies are heavily modified.

Working sample can be found here:

https://gitlab.com/alexej.vlasov/syncer/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml
- this project is using the prepared image and also it has a job to prepare this image.

https://gitlab.com/alexej.vlasov/maven/blob/master/Dockerfile
- dockerfile to run maven and download dependencies once.

The pros:

- don't need to download dependencies each time - they are inside a
  docker image (and docker layers are cached on the runners)
- don't need to upload artifacts when job is finished

Comment: Actually, I was using this strategy previously and didn't like it. So this is not a solution for me, because maven afaik doesn't have a command, that would reliably download all required dependencies. I had to create a hack, where I would force all the plugins to be executed, but also make them skip execution, so maven would also download the plugins (and their deps), so could I cache them in a docker layer.

Comment: Also, your solution requires running `mvn clean install` twice - once to build the Docker image, and then again in the build itself - that is not very effective. You're also rebuilding the image manually to re-create the caching image, I don't like that either.

Comment: You don't need to rebuild image every time. it's enough to run it once. you might want to refresh it sometime or once a week/month depending on your project.  Regarding dependencies. maven dependency plugin has goal go-offline. It downloads all required dependencies. Be sure to use latest version of that plugin since default version skips some plugins.